# System of Equations. Are there any solutions?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of equations
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
      .
       \begin{bmatrix}
         x\\
        y\\
         z\\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        -1 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Without solving the system, can you tell if there are any solutions? If so, how many?

Comment: If you heard about the Cramer method, you should be able to answer at a glance.

Comment: What is the determinant?

Comment: Cannot you just evaluate the determinant of the coefficient matrix? It is -2$\ne 0$. It has one solution.

Comment: In general: Calculating the determinant of a matrix is at least as expensive as inverting the matrix. Actually one of the least expensive ways the calculate the determinant is - inverting the matrix. So that should not be an option.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1.** Note that
$$\begin{align}&\qquad a(1,1,1)+b(-1,0,0)+c(1,1,-1)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow (a,a,a)+(-b,0,0)+(c,c,-c)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow (a-b+c,a+c,a-c)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow ((a+c)-b,a+c,a-c)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow (-b,a+c,a-c)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow (-b,a+c+(a-c),a-c)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow (-b,2a,a-c)=(0,0,0)\\\\
&\Longrightarrow a=b=c=0
\end{align}$$

This shows that row vectors of the coefficient matrix are linearly independent. Thus, by the theorem below, the original system has exactly one solution.

---

**Solution 2.** The associated homogeneous system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
      .
       \begin{bmatrix}
         x\\
        y\\
         z\\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
which can be written as 
$$\left\{\begin{align}x+y+z&=0\\-x&=0\\x+y-z&=0\end{align}\right.$$
has only the trivial solution.  Thus, by the theorem below, the original system has exactly one solution.

---

**Solution 3 (given in other answers and comments).** Note that
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\neq 0
$$
Thus, by the theorem below, the original system has exactly one solution.

---

> **Theorem 6.4.5 in [Anton & Rorres](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=loRbAgAAQBAJ&dq=anton+rorres+elementary+linear+algebra&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0uZqEjpvVAhWFPpAKHYgSAaEQ6AEIMzAC).**
>   If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, if $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and if $T_A:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n $ is multiplication by $A$, then the following are equivalent.
>
> (a) $A$ is invertible.
>   **(b) $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.**
>   (c) The reduced row-echelon form of $A$ is $I_n$.
>   (d) $A$ is expressible as a product of elementary matrices.
>   (e) $Ax=b$ is consistent for every $n\times 1$ matrix $b$.
>   **(f) $Ax=b$ has exactly one solution for every $n\times 1$ matrix $b$.
>
>   (g) $\mathbf{\det (A)\neq 0}$.**
>   (h) The column vectors of $A$ are linearly independent.
>   **(i) The row vectors of $A$ are linearly independent.**
>   (j) The column vectors of $A$ span $\mathbb R^n$.
>   (k) The row vectors of $A$ span $\mathbb R^n$.
>   (l) The column vectors of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.
>   (m) The row vectors of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.
>   (n) $A$ has rank $n$.
>   (o) $A$ has nullity $0$.
>   (p) The orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $A$ is $\mathbb R^n$.
>   (q) The orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$ is $\{0\}$.
>   (r) The kernel of $T_A$ is $\{0\}$.
>   (s) The range of $T_A$ is $\mathbb R^n$.
>   (t) $T_A$ is one-to-one.
>   (u) $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.
>   (v) $A^TA$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the determinant of the matrix is $(-1)\times 1\times 1 - (-1)\times1\times(-1) = -2$ so there is one unique solution.

Comment: Not that it really matters but the determinant is -2.

Comment: If the determinant turned out to be zero,  would the answer be infinite solutions or no solution?

Comment: @Ralph Could be both, what you defiinitely can say that there is at least not one unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second row, which immediately implies $x=1$, to the other two rows and inspect: 
$$
y-z=-2\\
y+z=-2\\
\implies y=-2, z=0
$$

As noted by @skyking, the determinant is nonzero, making the solution unique. Also note, every operation I did to find the solution $(1,-2,0)$ is injective, also implying our solution is unique.

Comment: This answer does not satisfies the OP requirement.

Comment: @Pedro. Indeed, it does not. I read the stipulation late and decided to leave my answer as I think the requirement is silly.

Comment: It is silly for practical purposes because the system is easy to solve. However, exercises like that are very important for beginners.

Comment: @Pedro that's a fair point.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you don't know the theory of the resolution of linear system of equations at all.*

The system is

$$\begin{align}x+y+z&=-1,\\-x&=-1,\\x+y-z&=-1.\end{align}$$

Obviously, $x$ is known and you can move it to the $RHS$ in all equations.

What remains is a system with the values of $y+z$ and $y-z$ known (whatever they are).

Then it is clear that by adding or subtracting these equations memberwise, you will eliminate every other unknown and get a well-defined solution to the system ($2x=\cdots,2y=\cdots$).

Answer (score 0):

For a system, $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$,  if $\mathbf{A}$ is square and the $\det (\mathbf{A}) \neq 0 $, then there is a unique solution. This means that $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible.

If $\mathbf{A}$ is not invertible, then $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$ will either have infinite solutions or no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the $3$ columns to be linearly dependent it is clear column $2$ and $3$ must be dependent. This is not true, so the $3$ columns are linearly independent, the matrix has full rank, and is invertible.