# Show that $\det(A) = 0$ without directly evaluating the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-4 &1 &1 &1 &1 \\
1&-4 &1 &1 &1\\
1 &1&-4 &1 &1\\
1 &1 &1&-4 &1\\
1 &1 &1 &1&-4
\end{pmatrix}$$

I know $\det(A) = 0$ when it has two identical rows or columns (no) or if it has two proportional rows (I can't see how they are proportional)

Comment: Observe the columns (and also the rows) sum to $0$.

Comment: There are many possible arguments. See the Theorem in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366432/70305). @KimJongUn comment uses $(g)\Leftrightarrow(i)$.

Comment: Add the columns $2$, $3$, $4$ to column $1$. The determinant does not change. Now you have the determinant of a matrix with first column $0$.

Comment: $A=-5I+U$ where $U$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix made by $1$s only. It follows that $$\text{Spec}(A)=-5+\text{Spec}(U) = -5+\{5,0,0,0,0\} = \{\color{red}{0},-5,-5,-5,-5\}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can we say that $Det(A)=-4\cdot Det(A')$ and $Det(A')=0$ as its rows of ones?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $NS(A) \ne \{ 0 \}$ then $\det(A) = 0$.  Can you find an element of the null space of $A$ by inspection?

Answer (score 2):

Sum the first 4 rows, multiply by -1 and insert this as replacement of row 4.  This new row 4 is identical to row 5 and the determinant is thus automatically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\det A\ne 0$ when the rows (or columns) are linearly independent. That is, if we have $a_1 r_1 + a_2r_2+a_3r_3+a_4r_4+a_5r_5=0$ where $r_i$ are the rows (or columns) expressed as vectors, then the only solution to this in terms of the $a_i$'s is $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=a_5=0$.

If you wish to prove that $\det A=0$ then toy can do this by showing the rows (or columns) are linearly dependent. Can you find a set of $a_i$'s such that $a_1 r_1 + a_2r_2+a_3r_3+a_4r_4+a_5r_5=0$?